# How to extract unusual unknown words in NLP

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, spacy

Im new to NLP and try to work with spacy, other libraries are also ok. 
In my dataset i have a lot of names of computerlocations and computer names like: WRN212 asnd WRN800 SKh1038 PHk2gd
This names are free formatted text in my dataset, does someone know how to extract such words.

Is this possible in Spacy?
Is there somewhere and example?

Thank you in advance.

Greets

Comment: This is too broad and too opinion-based for SO, but all of your examples contains letters and numbers. Might want to start there.

Comment: This is also off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unknown words" is a subjective term (names, cities, company names etc.), so it is hard to categorize that. If you are using Spacy, my best bet would be to use a Lemmatizer to check if the morphological root exists or not. If it doesn't, it is likely that your word is unknown (or misspelled). Here is how you can do it:

```
    from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
    lemmatizer = Lemmatizer()
    def is_unknown(word):
        return len(lemmatizer(word)) == 0
```